# Pass multiple record numbers into table/grid in report header in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to represent multiple record numbers in the report header in a form of a grid/table. Each record will contain a field called impact, which needs to be represented into a 3 by 3 grid/table in the report header. Each record will either fit into X1Y1 or X1Y2 or X1Y3 or etc.. or X3Y3. If the record fits into the range for each coordinate then the table or grid should show that record number in that area. Not sure how to be more specific or if it is even possible. Assistance is much appreciated.

Regards
Bips.za

Comment: Not able to understand the question. Can you please explain more..

Comment: Record 1. Name=Test1, Impact=10; Record 2. Name=Test2, Impact=20; Record 3. Name=Test3, Impact=30; Record 4. Name=Test4, Impact=40. I want to now represent the record number in a Grid, lets say 2 by 2, so in X1,Y1 area all record numbers of Impacts in the range between 1 to 10 (i.e record no 1), in X1,Y2 area all record numbers of Impacts in the range between 11 to 20(i.e record no 2), in X2,Y1 area all record numbers of Impacts in the range between 21 to 30(i.e record no 3) and in X1,Y1 area all record numbers of Impacts in the range between 30 to 40(i.e record no 4).Make a little more sense?

Comment: 1) What have you tried already? 2) What's the purpose of this? What is the significance of X and Y? Are they supposed to be column names? Are you basically wanting something that looks like an aging report? 3) Sounds like you need a cross tab with suppression rules or a subreport.